# Can there be a mean of a quantum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

If $e_i$ is one of the basis, does $\langle e_i\rangle$ have a significance? The mean of a physical variable $a$ associated with the operator $A$ is $\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle$, but can there be a mean of a state as well?

Answer (score 2):

No. First, the mean value of an operator given a quantum state corresponds with the mean value we would obtain of the associated physical observable upon repeated measurements of systems in the state $|\psi\rangle$ upon measurement.

However, the quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ itself is an abstract mathematical tool that tells us everything about our quantum system.. It can't take on a single value, so it doesn't have a mean value like the previous mean I discussed. It would be like asking in classical mechanics if the coordinates $(\mathbf x,\mathbf p)$ of a classical system has a mean value.

Comment: +1: I understand the impulse behind the last sentence but there is no distinction between the state and the operator in CM and thus, no real concept of an average value of either the state or the operator. The operators always have definite values and that is what characterizes the state. The concept of an average doesn't enter. However, one can go to classical statistical mechanics and find some analog: it doesn't mean anything to ask what is the average value of an ensemble. The meaningful thing is to ask the average value of an observable over the ensemble.

Comment: @FeynmansOutforGrumpyCat *there is no distinction between the state and the operator in CM* In CM the entire state is still different from a single coordinate. Although I do agree that the distinction isn't as strong as in QM.

Answer (score 0):

The observable is a linear hermitian operator acting on a state. It is not hard to see that there is no obvious action of the state on itself, so the state cannot be observable and cannot have the mean value.